# Try to use Langchain in my pure Javascript project but fail to compile. Module parse failed: Unexpected token (73:15)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, langchain

I have a pure javacsript project and I try to import Langchain. After I npm install Langchain, I try to import langchain version OpenAI.

```
import { OpenAI } from "langchain/llms/openai";
```

However, it failed to compaile:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/langchain/dist/llms/openai.js 73:15
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (73:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     var _this;
|     _classCallCheck(this, OpenAI);
>     if (fields?.modelName?.startsWith("gpt-3.5-turbo") || fields?.modelName?.startsWith("gpt-4") || fields?.modelName?.startsWith("gpt-4-32k")) {
|       // eslint-disable-next-line no-constructor-return, @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
|       return _possibleConstructorReturn(_this, new OpenAIChat(fields, configuration));
```

My package.json is like this:

```
{
  "name": "speechless",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1363.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "keyword-extractor": "^0.0.25",
    "langchain": "^0.0.101",
    "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk": "^1.27.0",
    "natural": "^6.2.0",
    "openai": "^3.2.1",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "react-speech-recognition": "^3.10.0",
    "react-toastify": "^8.1.0",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1",
    "uti": "^7.1.1",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start ",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I fix this, I found Langchain is the only tool supporting input very long text to ChatGPT API, I have to use it in my javascript project. Anyone could help?

I also try to install typescript to my project, it still doesn't work. When I do so, code can not run but output error, module can not find.

Comment: ran into a same issue... any findings from this?